# Apply function to column in sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have this table in sqlite3.

```
name,   currency,   price
AA,     SGD,        1
BB,     USD,        2
CC,     EUR,        3
```

I need to process the `price` in this manner.

```
if currency == "SGD", price = price*2 
if currency == "USD", price = price*3
if currency == "EUR", price = price*4
```

The output table after the processing will look like this;

```
name,   currency,   price
AA,     SGD,        2
BB,     USD,        6
CC,     EUR,        12
```

Is it possible to write some kind of function to process the `price` column in sql for sqlite3 databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    name,
    currency,
    CASE WHEN currency = 'SGD' THEN 2*price
         WHEN currency = 'USD' THEN 3*price
         WHEN currency = 'EUR' THEN 4*price
         ELSE price END AS price
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. It works. What if the processing gets more complicated? What if there is a need to retrieve the multiplier from another table? I asked another follow-up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866754/apply-function-to-column-that-requires-retrieving-column-from-another-sqlite-tab