# Apply processing or function to column that requires retrieving column from another sqlite table

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have this table `name_currency` in sqlite3.

```
name,   currency,   price
AA,     SGD,        1
BB,     USD,        2
CC,     EUR,        3
```

I need to process the price in this manner.

```
if currency == "SGD", price = price*X 
if currency == "USD", price = price*Y
if currency == "EUR", price = price*Z
```

The values of `X`, `Y`, `Z` needs to be retrieved from another table `currency_multiplier`. This is how `currency_multiplier` looks like.

```
name,   currency,   multiplier
AA,     SGD,        2  #value of X 
BB,     USD,        3  #value of Y
CC,     EUR,        4  #value of Z
```

The output table will look like this after processing `price` column;

```
name,   currency,   price
AA,     SGD,        2
BB,     USD,        6
CC,     EUR,        12
```

Is it possible to do this entirely in sql? One solution I have in mind is to retrieve the values from `name_currency`, then do the processing in a python function. However, I think it is more elegant to do it entirely in sql. Any hints on how to get started? Does SQL in sqlite3 support some form of function when processing becomes too complex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may join the `name_currency` table to the `currency_multiplier` table:

```
SELECT
    n.name,
    n.currency,
    c.multiplier * n.price AS price
FROM name_currency n
INNER JOIN currency_multiplier c
    ON n.name = c.name;
```

Note that this runs the risk of dropping currencies from the report which appear in `name_currency` but have no mapping in `currency_multiplier`.  But, in such a case, it is not clear how you would report anyway, because the multiplier/forex rate is not known.

Comment: You're a genius!

Comment: @user3848207 No genius.  Just have an unhealthy Stack Overflow addiction problem.

Comment: Is it possible to write sqlite custom functions when processing gets more complex? It is not easy to write SQL queries when processing gets complex.

Comment: I don't even know if all implementations of SQLite support user defined functions.  Even if it does, you should avoid UDFs unless you really can't easily write a query otherwise.  Most of the time, you won't need UDFs.

Comment: hmm ... I find SQL joins complicated to write. UDF are easier. I guess I have lots to learn from Stack Overflow geniuses here.